# Can Steinert syndrome be developed passed the thirties?

Tags: muscle, genetics, age, muscular-dystrophy

Can a person carrying the gene responsible of developing the Steinert syndrome start suffering it passed his/her thirties? What are the chances of developing the syndrome if a person carries that gene?

**NOTE**: I'd be grateful if you could upvote this question to gain reputation enough for creating these tags: **dystrophy**, **myotonic-distrophy**, **steinert-syndrome**